# WPF Style with no target type?

Tags: wpf, inheritance, styles

How can I have a WPF style that has no target type ( one that can be applied to all objects) ?

```
<Style x:Key="Basic" TargetType="???">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Tahoma"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
</Style>
```

I want to base all other styles on this "basic" style.

Regards,
MadSeb

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Append "Control." to the beginning of the Property, and remove the TargetType.  Then, in the styles that derive from it, use BasedOn with a StaticResource pointing at the base Style.

```
<Style x:Key="basicStyle">
    <Setter Property="Control.FontFamily" Value="Tahoma" />
    <Setter Property="Control.FontSize" Value="12" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" BasedOn="{StaticResource basicStyle}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource basicStyle}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource basicStyle}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,4" />
</Style>
```