# Styling an attached property with inheritance

Tags: wpf, styles, attached-properties

My question is similar to this: [WPF Style with no target type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925170/wpf-style-with-no-target-type) but the problem is that mine is an attached property:

```
<Style TargetType="Shape" >
    <Setter  Property="z:Zommable.Unscale" Value="StrokeThickness" />
</Style>
```

My goal is: all object deriving from shape must have the attached property Zommable.Unscale with a value, but I can't find how to do it.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no difference to the other question. you will have to do *exactly* the same. So for each class deriving from Shape you will have to use a Style with that targettype that's BasedOn your style with your attached property.

So it's gonna be:

```
<Style x:Key="basicStyle">
    <Setter Property="z:Zommable.Unscale" Value="StrokeThickness" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}" BasedOn="{StaticResource basicStyle}">
    <!-- ... -->
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}" BasedOn="{StaticResource basicStyle}">
    <!-- ... -->
</Style>

<!-- ... -->
```